How to Fix ‘Transaction Log is Full’ Error in SQL Server
I’m frequently encountering the ‘transaction log is full’ error in SQL Server. I’ve tried increasing the log size and taking backups, but the issue persists. What steps can I take to prevent this error from happening in the future?

"I’ve tried ... taking backups" - What type of backups?

You can query sys.databases and check column log_reuse_wait_desc to see if anything blocking you from reclaiming log file space. If it's ,

LOG_BACKUP - then schedule a job for log backups
ACTIVE_TRANSACTION- check if there any long running transaction
REPLICATION- if there is problems in replicating data to subscriber.

Other possible values https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
If the value is NOTHING you may try shrinking log file.
